# Possible to use Docker machine with continuous integration tools?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, digital-ocean, docker-machine

What I'm trying to do: use a continuous integration tool like CircleCI or GitLab to deploy to a DigitalOcean droplet. Locally I'm able to use Docker Machine to run something like

`$ eval $(docker-machine env my-droplet)`

to connect to an already created droplet and then `docker run foo`.

Is it possible to do such an action via the traditional deploy.yml file? Assume that I have a `digitalocean-access-token` and a droplet already created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you can use this command to achieve what you want:

`docker-machine create \
  --driver generic \
  --generic-ip-address=<your vm IP> \
  --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  my-droplet`

And then you can do as you want:

`$ eval $(docker-machine env my-droplet)`

This will register the machine. Otherwise you have to provide all certs and configs from your dev env to your CI which is not secure and recommended.

Comment: Thanks, Boynux. I've already created the machine locally that way. Will using the commands you describe above as part of my deploy.yml attach to the already-created droplet? And also, I presumably need to install docker-machine as part of the CI deploy script?

Comment: Thanks @boynux, I didn't realize the generic driver could be used like that (and I read more about it in the official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/). That seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The integration proposed by DigitalOcean is more with Docker Cloud, meaning your CI should push your image to Docker Cloud, for DigitalOcean to use in a Droplet.

See "[Deploy Horizon Using Docker Cloud & DigitalOcean](http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/devops/deploy-horizon-using-docker-cloud-digitalocean#bAfwkQxFwCUX8gOT.99)" from **[Chris Asche](https://twitter.com/devcasche)**

> log into Docker Cloud  and link your DigitalOcean account. To do this, click on 'Cloud Settings' at the bottom left. You should now see a list of Cloud Providers on the page. Click on the plug icon next to DigitalOcean to link your accounts. Note that, at the time of writing, there is a $20 credit added to your DigitalOcean account when linked with Docker Cloud.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pluralsight/guides/master/images/d0ffee77-f47c-41ac-942d-3d02f8b3d42f.png]

> Once your accounts are linked, create a new DigitalOcean Node Cluster. I'm going to call mine, `horizon-with-docker` in the region `Toronto 1`.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pluralsight/guides/master/images/82fcfbc6-5e4c-4038-8ce4-152c54bbf711.png]

> The newly created node cluster can be used to run a stack. A stack is a collection of services and each service is a collection of containers. Stacks are created with the [`stack-yaml` file](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/stack-yaml-reference/).

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pluralsight/guides/master/images/9109de97-3698-4f44-9d10-15b7e5e6970d.png]

> Once created, revisit the node cluster created earlier to grab the IP address of your DigitalOcean droplet - my droplet IP is 159.203.61.66. Go ahead and visit your freshly deployed Horizon application at the IP address.